# Is $\frac {\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac {dy}{dx}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is $\dfrac {\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\dfrac {dy}{dx}$?

In one of the proofs of differentiation I saw the following steps:
$$\dfrac {\Delta y}{\Delta x}=……$$
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=………$$

I just want to know is $\dfrac {\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\dfrac {dy}{dx}$.? If yes, how? Are there any conditions / constraints for this?

Comment: If $y=mx+b$, then $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{dy}{dx}$.....

Comment: One big difference is that $\Delta y$ and $\Delta x$ can have numeric values on their own, whereas $dy$ and $dx$ do not have stand-alone values. The latter are only meaningful in a ratio, or using Leibniz's concept of "differentials".

Comment: In the non-standard point of view, $\Delta y$ is the resulting change in $y$ from an infinitesimal change in $x$. The expression $\Delta y/ \Delta x$ is then infinitely close to $dy/dx$ but they are different. In the standard view, this is dealt with by 'taking the limit' as the increment goes to $0$. This is because in the standard view, there are no infinitesimals, so the increment is finite. Thus you have to take the limit as that finite amount goes to $0$. In summary, in the standard view, you take limits to turn one into the other. In the non-standard view they are infinitely close.

Comment: I bet that the thing you just showed did _not_ appear in the proof you were reading (not even if you fill in the "......" parts). There was probably text in between, or extra symbols such as $\lim_{\Delta x\to0},$ or different things on the right side of the two $=$ signs. This would be a better question if you edited it to more faithfully represent what the proof actually claimed.

Comment: @DavidK You're questioning Albert Einstein?

Comment: @MarkViola https://randysrandom.com/einstein-on-the-internet/  Of course, you knew that already. :-)

Comment: @DavidK Now that was funny.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, $$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Answer (score 3):

When the change in $x$, I.e. $\Delta x$ is infinitesimally small, then the it is converted into derivative. What I mean to say is

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{dy}{dx}$$